# Not able to initiate the List<customer>. The value of Customers.Names is null

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ConsoleApp3;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customers customers = new Customers();
            List<Customers> names = new List<Customers>()
            {
                new Customers {Names = "Tanveer"},
                new Customers {Names = "Nabila"},
                new Customers {Names = "Suraj"}
            };  

            foreach (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customers.Names.Length);
            }
        }
        class Customers
        {
            public string Names { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create the list of Customers and write it on the Console. But the Customers.Names is null. I am new to programming so please help.Thanks

Comment: make it: `Console.WriteLine(names[i].Names);` .... because that actually contains the data

Comment: Comment `Customers customers = new Customers();` out. Once you do that, your other mistake (of using `customers` inside the loop) will become clear.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code, as is, does not compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let us fix up that naming. Naming is very important, but also one of the more annoying parts.

```
//Singular for the class
class Customer
{
  //Also Singular, as this can only take 1 name
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

//Plural, because it is a collection of Customer Instances.
List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>()
{
  new Customer {Name = "Tanveer"},
  new Customer {Name = "Nabila"},
  new Customer {Name = "Suraj"}
};
```

Then you itterate over it using:

```
//Use a proper foreach, no need to deal with Indexes here
foreach (Customer current in Customers){
  Console.WriteLine(current.Name);
}
```

If you do want to have a running counter, this is how the loop would look:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Customers.Count;i++){
  //I you get any Exceptions, you want to split it up over 2 lines using a temporary variable
  Console.WriteLine(Customers[i].Name);
}
```

What you had in your code was a bastardisation of for and foreach syntax, wich I doubt compiled.

Comment: There may be other reasons the user is using a for loop here -- might want to show how that would work if it is needed.

Comment: @Hogan: Added it.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Console.WriteLine(names[i].Names);
```

Comment: `names[i].Names`

Answer (score 1):

`customers.Names` is null because `customers` is an object which you haven't populated with any data, and has no obvious purpose. `names` is the actual list of customers with useful info in it.

`names` does not have a Names property directly either, though. The objects within the list do. So you need to refer to a specific object within the specific list.

And since you're in a loop for doing just that, `names[i].Names.Length` is no doubt what you intended.

N.B. However it needs to be a `for` rather than `foreach` in the loop definition - the syntax used with `foreach` is different. This shouldn't have compiled in order to allow you to even see the `null` output, so perhaps this is just a typo in your posted code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(names[i].Names.Length);
}
```

should be closer to what you need (although I'm not convinced you really are intending to print the length of each name...but that's up to you).

P.S. You should probably amend your naming convention so you've got `Customer` as the type and `Name` as the property. It's much more readable and comprehensible if they're singular rather than plural.

Comment: The OP probably doesn't need the `.Length`, and just wants the names.

Comment: @mjwills I was going off the `Customers.Names is null` in the description which is capitalised. But now you point out, that's not true of the actual code. And it probably just wouldn't compile anyway. I'll amend.

Comment: @computercarguy very likely. But I'm not going to second-guess. They didn't mention an objective. So I'll leave it as-is unless OP specifies otherwise.